# Rails SQL Server failed connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, tiny-tds

it's my first time trying to get a rails app to connect to an external database.

I've installed active-record-sql-server-adapter and Tiny_Tds successfully and in the rails console I am able to connect to the database just fine.

when I try to connect from the actual application however (run migrations, pull data, etc.) I get this error:

> Tiny_Tds::Error: Adaptive Server connection failed (localhost)

Please help

Comment: Do you have the contents of your `database.yml` file, and are you running rails in the same `RAILS_ENV` as the rails console?

Comment: ```development:
  primary:
    <<: *default
    database: db/development.sqlite3
 
  outside:
    database: master
    adapter: sqlserver
    host: localhost
    port: 1433
    user: 
    password: 
    azure: true 

(left out credentials intentionally here)

and yes when i run the migration i run 

```rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Comment: can you edit your question to include any new information?  after doing a quick google search, I found this: https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds/issues/266#issuecomment-211523931 can you take a look at that and see if it helps?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do that, i actually came across that before i came here and from what i understand that threads solution was making sure that when tsql -C ran, openSSL had a value of yes.

In my code openSSL already has a value of yes , so i don't think that's my issue

Answer (score 0):

In the error you received it mentions `localhost`, and that is the host you've got configured in `database.yml` as well.  Should instead be your Azure server host name, something ending in "database.windows.net".

There is also a reference to a sqlite database file that can be removed -- pull out the line `database: db/development.sqlite3`.  And instead of `user:` it should be `username:`.  Putting all of that together, try something like this:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  encoding: utf8
  username:   (left out credentials intentionally here)
  password:   (left out credentials intentionally here)
  host: {xxx-xxx-xxx}-sqlserver.database.windows.net
  port: 1433
  azure: true
  database: <your database name>
```

More info about configuring an Azure connection is described in the docs from the rails gem **[The Brick](https://github.com/lorint/brick)**.